# How would you speed up this code? Reducing the resolution of data from a netcdf and then converting it to xyz format for stats

Tags: r, optimization, geospatial, netcdf, rworldmap

I'm taking a netcdf of maize yields and area harvested, shrinking the resolution from 2.5 arc-minutes to .5degrees, and then converting the whole thing to XYZ format so that I can make it "talk" more easily to data that I've got in that format.  (I suppose that I could turn my other data into matrix form, but I like xyz.)

The data is [here](http://www.geog.mcgill.ca/landuse/pub/Data/175crops2000/NetCDF/maize_5min.nc.zip).

The code below defines a few functions to calculate total production from area harvested and average yields, and then it makes some "feeder" data t use when querying the netcdf's, then it uses plyr to loop through the feeder, extract the data, apply the functions, and then save in xyz.  It works, but it takes about 30 minutes to run only one of these files, and I've got more than 100.  Any suggestions for ways to optimize this code would be great.  Would it be faster to extract bigger chunks of data and apply functions to them?  Like, maybe a whole stripe of the earth?  How would I know a priori whether this would be faster or not?

```
rm(list=ls()) 
library(ncdf)
library(reshape)
library(plyr)
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(rworldmap)

getha = function(lat,size=lat[1]-lat[2]){
    lat1 = (lat-size/2)*pi/180
    lat2 = (lat+size/2)*pi/180
    lon1 = (0-size/2)*pi/180    #lon doesn't come in because all longitudes are great circles
    lon2 = (0+size/2)*pi/180
    6371^2 * abs(sin(lat1)-sin(lat2))*abs(lon1-lon2)*100    #6371 is the radius of the earth and 100 is the number of ha in a km^2
    }

gethamat = function(mat,latvec,blocksize=6){
    a = getha(latvec)
    areamat = matrix(rep(a,blocksize),blocksize)
    area = t(mat)*areamat   #The matrix is transposed because the dimensions of the Ramankutty's netcdf's are switched
    area
    }

getprod = function(yieldblock,areablock,latvec){
    b = gethamat(areablock,latvec)
    sum(t(yieldblock)*b,na.rm=TRUE)
    }

lat = as.matrix(seq(from=89.75,to=-89.75,by=-.5))
lon = as.matrix(seq(from=-179.75,to=179.75,by=.5))

lon = seq.int(from=1,to=4320,by=6)
lat = seq.int(from=1,to=2160,by=6)

lat = rep(lat,720)
lon = t(matrix(lon,720,360))
lon = as.data.frame(lon)
l = reshape(lon,direction="long",varying=list(colnames(lon)),v.names = "V")
coords = data.frame(cbind(l[,2],lat))
colnames(coords) = c("lng","lat")
feeder = coords
head(feeder)

maize.nc = open.ncdf('maize_5min.nc')

getcrops = function(feed,netcdf,var="cropdata"){
    yieldblock = get.var.ncdf(netcdf,varid=var,start = c(as.numeric(feed[1]),as.numeric(feed[2]),2,1),count = c(6,6,1,1))
    areablock = get.var.ncdf(netcdf,varid=var,start = c(as.numeric(feed[1]),as.numeric(feed[2]),1,1),count = c(6,6,1,1))
    lat = get.var.ncdf(netcdf,varid="latitude",start = feed[2],count = 6)
    prod = getprod(yieldblock,areablock,lat)
    lon = get.var.ncdf(netcdf,varid="longitude",start = feed[1],count = 6)
    #print(c(mean(lat),mean(lon)))
    data.frame(lat=mean(lat),lon = mean(lon),prod=prod)
    }

out = adply(as.matrix(feeder),1,getcrops,netcdf=maize.nc,.parallel=FALSE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`plyr` functions are notoriously slow when the number of chunks grows larger. I would really recommend keeping the data in a multi-dimensional array. This allows you to use `apply` to e.g. get mean for all `lat-lon` combinations etc. The multi-dimensional array takes less RAM storage, as the metadata is not in stored directly as columns, but implicitly within the dimensions of the array. In addition, `apply` is often much much faster than using `plyr`. The `ncdf` package natively reads the data into multi-dimensional arrays, so this also saves you a processing step (e.g. using `melt`).

After reducing the dataset, I would often use `melt` to go to what you call XYZ format for plotting. But by then the dataset is so small that this does not really mattern.